# Can valid XML contain a singular sharp-brace-enclosed word

Tags: xml

Is it valid XML to have a single word in sharp braces?

```
<data>
    <message param1="sth">
         Here is text concernthing data (<Pass>#150)
    </message>
</data>
```

XML validator says it is invalide, but there are no other nodes between `<message>` and `</message>` and the beautifier I have seems to work easily with it. Is it just not strict "good practice" but in some way workable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is invalid and XML parsers should throw an error on encountering it.

If you want to use `<` and `>` as data, then use `&lt;` and `&gt;` or CDATA blocks.

Answer (score 1):

All XML tags must either be closed with a matching close-tag (`<Pass></Pass>`) or be self-closing (`<Pass />`).

All instances of `<` or `>` *not* intended as an XML tag must be escaped as `&lt;`/`&gt;` or enclosed in a CDATA block , e.g. `<![CDATA[Text with < and > in it]]>`.